# Youtube Quota on new Project

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube

I am using the Youtube API with Apps Script for the first time but I get a quota error. I activated the Youtube API from the Apps Script window, and added my scripts.

Note I am using a Google Workspace account. I didn't have this problem with my private google account.

Here is the code that generates the error:

```
    function getVids() {
  var list = YouTube.Search.list('id,snippet', {
    channelId: 'UCYf_kU_HoMOUUe3hW-0ou5Q',
    maxResults: 25
  })

  var json = JSON.parse(list);
  var items = list.items;
  var allVideos = [];
  for (var i=1; i<items.length;i++) {
    var videoId = list.items[i].id.videoId;
    allVideos.push(videoId);
  }
  console.log(allVideos)
}
```

I receive this error:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to youtube.videos.insert failed
> with error: The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded
> your [quota](/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota).

I tried looking at the consumption here: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard but it redirects me to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard?project=northern-math-286006&folder=&organizationId= which I assume is some default project name as I didn't choose it. I selected https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?folder=&organizationId=&project=northern-math-286006 from this page to view Youtube data but it returns "No data is available for the selected time frame."

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation:

According to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota) you have exceeded **10,000 units per day**.

Unit points might be a little tricky to understand but there is a very good explanation on the link above itself:

[image]

You are doing **SEARCH** requests and for every search request you spend **100** units. I assume you have executed this code and/or other codes that consume points and this is why you reached your maximum unit points.

According to the documentation [here](https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/quotas) you can see your quota usage but you might need to have permission to access that info.

### [YouTube Data API (v3) - Quota Calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost):

> If your application calls a method, such as search.list, that returns
> multiple pages of results, each request to retrieve an additional page
> of results incurs the estimated quota cost.

Comment: Thanks Mario's. Actually I just activated the API. I failed to upload a video because I got a message that I was out of quota so I wrote this other script to to check videos because it uses less quota. So I don't see how I could have exceeded the 10000 unit limit.

Comment: This quota is not per script. Is the sum of usage for every script that you have ran today. @michaeldon

Comment: Hi Marios. Yes I understand. I got an error right away as soon as I turned on the API.

Comment: @michaeldon maybe the quota is less for your account for some reason. Can you contact the admin of your account if it is a workspace account ?

Comment: Heh well I am the admin as it's just me :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your quota for this API? You can find your quotas under 'IAM &A Admin' -> Quotas. Then look for 'YouTube Data API V3'.
Click on the one saying 'Queries per day' and see if the Limit is set to 0.
If yes, you might try to disable this API and enable again.

I had this issue too, and after disabling and enabling the API I get the 10k units.